# Liferay Inter Portlet Communication in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, liferay, communication, portlet

I'm developing liferay jsf portlet application and using liferay plugin sdk 6.2.0 and primefaces. I have two portlets in same portlet plugin project. I can do IPC with public render parameters but they should be same portal page. I tried to event mechanism but I couldn't succeed. Receiver event didn't fire. I did all xml definitions etc. What I'm doing wrong? Could you please share with me your opinions? If you have any sample working code, please share with me I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer : http://liferay-blogging.blogspot.in/2011/05/inter-portlet-communication-in-liferay.html (download menu may help you)

Comment: thanks for your comment Bhavin.This link is dead,I've already seen and tried that article,but didn't work

Comment: Have you tried to use a session bean for IPC? At least in an application server like JBoss this is working for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all comments and answers. I realized that IPC with public render parameters on different pages is possible via portal-ext file definition. I solved my problem this definition.

```
portlet.public.render.parameter.distribution=ALL_PORTLETS
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you download the [jsf2-ipc-events-customers-portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos#jsf2-ipc-events-customers-portlet) and [jsf2-ipc-events-bookings-portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos#jsf2-ipc-events-bookings-portlet) and try them in your environment. If they work then you can follow the patterns found in the source code in your own projects.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just pass the value as plain "servlet type" parameter. On receiver side, get the ServletRequest from PortletRequest using LR API. After that you can access that parameter. This is not a "JSR standard" approach but it would get you what you need.